# Pivot in SQL Server with Subtotal and Grand Total

Tags: sql-server

I want to PIVOT my table with Sub Total and Grand Total, here's my query, I don't know how to expand my query to get the totals.

```
SELECT *
FROM 
( SELECT DESC,STATUS
 FROM MASTER 
 ) rc
PIVOT
( COUNT(DESC)
 FOR STATUS IN ( [ACTIVE], [INACTIVE])
 ) AS pvt
```

Records:

```
AAA    ACTIVE
AAA    ACTIVE
AAA    INACTIVE
BBB    ACTIVE
BBB    INACTIVE
CCC    ACTIVE
DDD    INACTIVE
```

Desired result:

```
DESC   ACTIVE  INACTIVE TOTAL
------------------------------
AAA    2       1        3
BBB    1       1        2
CCC    1       0        1
DDD    0       1        1
TOTAL  4       3        7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built in PIVOT syntax is proprietary and quite limiting.  Many times it's more straightforward to use conditional aggregation.  The total count per row group by partition could be accomplished with COUNT(*).  The total per column could be added by a separate query which is appended using UNION ALL.

Something like this

```
with union_cte as (
    select [DESC], 1 sort_order,
           SUM(case when [status]='ACTIVE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [Active],
           SUM(case when [status]='INACTIVE ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [INACTIVE],
           count(*) [TOTAL]
    from [master] 
    group by [DESC]
    union all 
    select 'TOTAL', 2 sort_order,
           SUM(case when [status]='ACTIVE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [Active],
           SUM(case when [status]='INACTIVE ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [INACTIVE],
           count(*) [TOTAL]
    from [master])
select *
from union_cte
order by sort_order, [DESC];
```